# Go back for 2 segues while clicking at back button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have  3 `ViewControllers` which segue operations is prepared more or less like this:

`A --editview-> B ---showEdited->C`

Where `A` is for list of objects `B` is for edit certain object and `C` is for showing edited object. At this moment when user is getting into `C` and trying to go back he is landing in edit state `B` instead of a list.
Is it possible to close segue while performing to the new one? so that user will be back from `C` to `A`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand correctly what you want to do but I hope this will work.

```
 if let firstVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(firstVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into unwind segues. Unwind segues help when you have a sequence of VCs, say 1 -> 2 -> 3, and an unwind segue takes you from 3 directly back to 1.

Try these links:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Hope this helped.

Comment: It's best to summarize the contents of links when you post them, in case the pages you've linked to ever die or are no longer accessible.